# Lenovo X1: Increasing temperature and jittery window movement

Tags: lenovo, intel, temperature

I am not sure where to post this, because I seem to actually have two problems, one related to my hardware, and one related to Ubuntu. I need help separating and isolating them, and also solving the Ubuntu related one.

I have a Lenovo X1 (3rd gen), with an i7-5500U, which includes an integrated Intel HD Graphics 5500. I *think* I'm using i915 1.6.0 (dmesg mentions it).

I recently purchased a 4K monitor. I already realized that 4K was not possible over the docking station (bummer), but when using the internal mDP port, it works (in both Windows and Ubuntu). So far, so good, I have 4K with 60Hz.

However, two things happen:

1. My temperature increases noticeable (around 65° when idling or under light usage), and the fan speeds up (around 4000 RPM). Also, the right (fan) side gets noticeably warm, almost on the hot side.
2. I notice graphics lag, windows jitter when moving, and I have the general feeling that the CPU/GPU is struggling to keep up with something.

The temperature increase is barely reproducible under Windows (instead of 40 -> 65, the increase is more like 50 -> 55). The lag is not present under Windows at all, so I start to blame something Ubuntu-related for it.

In any case, where do I start to diagnose this problem? I don't want to randomly install packages or run commands I don't understand, and everything graphics-related in Linux has also been a magic don't-touch thing for me.

Thanks in advance!